# In react how to call properties from model.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am a beginner at react. I couldn't figure out how to import and use properties from Model.ts to NotesPage.tsx.
Here it is NotesPage.tsx

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import {
AutoComplete,
Form,
Input,
Button,
Select,
Cascader,
DatePicker,
}   from "antd";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../Css/NotesPageCss.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import { PostType } from "../model";

function NotesPage() {
 const [form] = Form.useForm();
 const [IsPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);

 const handleSubmit = (values: any) => {



 const blog = {
  PostType.studentId1,
  firstName,
  lastName,
  password,
  email,
  country,
  city,
  userName,
  gender,
  birthDate: new Date(),
};
```

Here it is Model.ts

```
export type PostType={
studentId1:number;
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
passWord: string;
email: string;
country:number;
city: number;
userName: string;
gender: number;
}
```

Now as you see, I already assigned all properties in model.ts. But I can't use them in NotesPage.tsx. How can I use them in NotesPage.tsx?

Comment: What you want is passing data from Model.ts to NotesPage.tsx component. There is concept of props in react for this purpose. You can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: Thanks for help. Now I figured it out with props